# Will there be a conflict between names and usecols of read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have several csv files and want to extract the third column of all the files into another csv file。But I  had a  problem。
All csv files as below. It's just that the values of the third column are different

```
test_indexs,test_labels,predicts_labels
0,0,57
1,0,83
2,0,0
3,0,70
4,0,0
5,0,0
```

My extraction code：

```
    for i in range(10):
          real_label = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+".csv",
                                     header=0, names=[i], usecols=[2])
```

The extracted data is as follows：

```
0,1,2,3,4
57,83,0,0,0
83,0,1,0,83
0,0,2,0,83
70,70,3,92,45
0,0,4,0,0
0,0,5,0,0
0,0,6,0,0
0,0,7,0,0
0,0,8,0,0
0,0,9,57,0
57,57,10,57,57
```

The first line is  header。
The extracts of the other columns are all correct, but not correct when extracting the third column of the 3rd csv file。That's the third column above

The third csv file is as follows：

```
test_indexs,test_labels,predicts_labels
0,0,0
1,0,0
2,0,0
3,0,70
4,0,0
5,0,0
6,0,0
7,0,92
8,0,0
```

It looks like I didn't succeed in extracting the third column of the original file, but instead extracted the first column of the original file。
Is this because there is a conflict between names and usecols when I use read_csv

Comment: the third csv file is different length to the other csv files...  how are you extracting columns of different lengths ?

Comment: In fact, it is the same, no matter the number of rows or columns. My csv files are very large, so I just copied some data.

Answer (score 0):

Finally，I used a non-clever approach

```
for i in range(10):
          real_label = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+".csv",
                                     header=0, names=[i], usecols=[2])
          if sort_csv_i == 2:
                real_label[2] = pd.read_csv(path+str(i)+".csv",
                                        usecols=[2])
```

This will get the results I want, although I don't know why